# Is the "api" part of a Web API route considered by Android's Uri.Builder as part of the authority or a path?

Tags: java, android, path, authority, authoritykeyidentifier

I've tried both of these:

```
builder.scheme("http").authority("10.0.2.2:28642").appendPath("api").appendPath("DeliveryItems").appendPath("PostArgsAndXMLFileAsStr").

builder.scheme("http").authority("10.0.2.2:28642/api").appendPath("DeliveryItems").appendPath("PostArgsAndXMLFileAsStr").
```

...and although for other reasons the code is not working yet, I'm wondering which way is right:

```
.authority("10.0.2.2:28642").appendPath("api").
```

-or:

```
authority("10.0.2.2:28642/api").
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "authority" portion of a URI identifies who's responsible for specifying the semantics of the path portion. This is usually a host/port combination and can optionally include a username/password (as in `http://user:pass@host:port/somepage`).

[Wikipedia has more details on the grammar of URIs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Comment: So you're saying that "api" is NOT part of the authority?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon No, it's not; it's part of the path. That first slash after the hostname/port separates the authority and the path.